# TypeError defining/accessing interceptors in AngularJS/TypeScript/ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following interceptor:

```
"use strict";

import { IApiService } from '../services/api';
import { ISessionService } from '../services/session';
import { IRedirectService } from '../services/redirect';

export default class ApiInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private $q: ng.IQService,
    private ApiService: IApiService,
    private SessionService: ISessionService,
    private RedirectService: IRedirectService) { }

  ...

}
```

This is how it's set as a Service:

```
import ApiInterceptor          from './interceptors/api';
...

export default angular.module('app.core', [
    'toastr', 'js-data'
  ])

  // Constants
  .constant('config', config)

  // Config
  .config(DataConfig)

  // Filters
  ...

  // Interceptors
  .service('ApiInterceptor', ApiInterceptor);
```

Then in my `app.instance` I set `app.core` as dep:

```
'use strict';

import '../app.core/module';
...

export default angular.module('app.instance', [
  ...
  'app.core',
  ...]);
```

And use its code here:

```
'use strict';

import '../../app.core/module';
...

export default function ConfigApp($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $analyticsProvider): void {
  ...
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ApiInterceptor');
  ...
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

This the information I get from debugger:

[image]

Going up the Call Stack:

[image]

Any ideas? I've been beating my head against the wall since yesterday...
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's a service example:

```
.service('LogService', LogService)
```

This is the implementation:

```
"use strict";

export interface ILogService {
  debug(...args: any[]): void;
  info(...args: any[]): void;
  warn(...args: any[]): void;
  error(...args: any[]): void;
  deprecated(...args: any[]): void;
  enableDebug(flag: boolean): void;
  enableConsole(flag: boolean): void;
}

/**
 * Provides logging support.
 */
export default class LogService implements ILogService {

  static debugEnabled: boolean = false;
  static consoleEnabled: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private $log: any,
    private $window: ng.IWindowService) { }
```

I get the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code :

```
// Interceptors
  .service('ApiInterceptor', ApiInterceptor);
```

Angular interceptors are *factories* and you cannot use *classes* for it. :

```
// Interceptors
  .factory('ApiInterceptor', somePlainOldFunctionAndNotAClassConstructor);
```

Comment: Ok, I did try that before posting here. My code was like this: `.factory('ApiInterceptor', function() {
  return { get: function() { return ApiInterceptor;} };
  })` but that didn't work as well, since the object was always undefined. Or did I do it incorrectly? Thanks for your answer, btw.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, the same thing happen with my services: `.service('SessionService', SessionService)` where `SessionService` is also a class.

Comment: `Or did I do it incorrectly.` Yes. You want to return an instance. Just wrapping it up to return the class doesn't fix anything

Comment: `Also, I forgot to mention, the same thing happen with my services:` that is a seperate question.

Comment: Thanks! but is the solution the same?

Comment: No. `.service('SessionService', SessionService)` is right. Perhaps you didn't want a service? e.g. interceptors cannot be a service ... how are you using `SessionService`. If you post more code I can have a look

Comment: Thanks. I updated my thread with the service information, please, let me know if that's enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @eestein I see `export default class`. Don't do that. But if you do make sure you `import` it correctly. There is no type safety in calling `.service` and you might not be passing it the class

Comment: Yup, that is correct. I do check that before using, I import the correct class: `import LogService              from './services/log';`